# How to collect all value from result query mongodb become array

Tags: mongodb, find

How to collect all value from result query mongodb become array, example

when i execute this query "db.organisms.find()", i get result like bellow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("8686cdcdc89798797"),
    "name" : "Horse",
    "parent" : "animal",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("90808dsdd55679sss"),
    "name" : "Cow",
    "parent" : "animal",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("908890dsddsd000808"),
    "name" : "Rose",
    "parent" : "flower",
}
```

How query to get result like this :

```
result = ["animal", "flower"]
```

how do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.collections.distinct()` operation should do the trick.

```
db.organisms.distinct("parent");
```